# Django allauth change password without logging out

Tags: python, django, logout, django-allauth, change-password

I'm using Django allauth for my authentication and I want to be able to stay logged in after changing the password. The allauth docs say that it is possible with:

```
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_PASSWORD_CHANGE =False
```

[image]

but I can't make it work. Has anyone here managed to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this might be related to [issue 1262](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/1262).

It was fixed in version [0.24.0](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/35d0621743ce22de3f3cdad23288ea483447f275/docs/changelog.rst#from-0240), so make sure you have upgraded.

Comment: Thanks for this I guess I have to upgrade.. btw do you know what is the procedure to upgrade allauth? From the docs I can't see the instructions

Comment: If you used pip to install it, you can upgrade with `pip install - -upgrade django-allauth`. I don't know whether there are any allauth specific things you'll have to do (e.g. migrations). Checking the changelog might be a good idea. I haven't used allauth so can't offer any more advice about upgrading.

Comment: If you used pip to install it, you can upgrade with `pip install --upgrade django-allauth`. I don't know whether there are any allauth specific things you'll have to do (e.g. migrations). Checking the changelog might be a good idea. I haven't used allauth so can't offer any more specific advice about upgrading.